# Can I name an CSV export with a range/cell number from the original worksheet and also save a PDF version?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been creating a quote & Order spreadsheet.
I have been testing VBA to simplify options for the user, however I am finding it difficult to name the export CSV and PDF Files automatically with the order number and client name. I have got the VBA to work for the PDF option but not the CSV.
The order number is in cell "O14" and the Client Name is in "N14".

The code I have tried is:

```
Sub CopyCells()

 ' export Macro

 Range("G8:O60").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Workbooks.Add
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
  "C:Users\Desktop\Invoices\Book2.csv" _
  , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:Users\Desktop\pdf\myPDFFile.pdf" _

'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     Filename:=Range("N14").Value & "_" & Range("O14").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Filename := "C:Users\Desktop\pdf\" & _
             Range("N14").Value & "_" & Range("O14").Value & ".pdf"
```